# Error importing PyTorch - Python

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pytorch

I have tried to install PyTorch using the following command in terminal:

```
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch-0.2.0.post1-cp27-none-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl
```

I then run the following code in python:

```
import torch
torch.__file__
```

and get the following error:

```
 File "/Users/brian/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
import torch._dl as _dl_flags

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_dl'
```

I have attempted to research the issue but cannot find a clear answer. any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: 
These are the results from trying to re-install PyTorch using the following commands:

```
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch-0.2.0.post1-cp27-none-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl 
pip install torchvision
```

Results:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from torch==0.2.0.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from torch==0.2.0.post1)


Requirement already satisfied: torchvision in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from torchvision)
Requirement already satisfied: torch in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from torchvision)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from torchvision)
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from torchvision)
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pillow->torchvision)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in ./anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from torch->torchvision)
```

EDIT II

The following command:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cuda80 -c soumith
```

yields this result:

```
Fetching package metadata ...........

PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:

   - cuda80

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/soumith/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/soumith/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
```

Comment: Seems the installation is not well done or you miss some package. Which Mac OS are you using? I have installed it a few days ago, and I didn't have the same problem.  To be sure, have you run these commands: 
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch-0.2.0.post1-cp27-none-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl 
pip install torchvision 
Right?

Comment: I have added the terminal response to doing this again in the question. Do you happen to know the terminal command to uninstall pytorch and I can try that?

Comment: @BrianPeach It seems you have anaconda installed on your mac, please try the following option instead: `conda install pytorch torchvision cuda80 -c soumith`

Comment: Updated question with the results from this command. I also tried without the cuda80 -c soumith and it could not find the pytorch package

Comment: @BrianPeach You don't have cuda installed, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On http://pytorch.org/ With:

- OS: OSX
- Package Manager: pip
- Python: 2.7
- CUDA: None

I've got:

```
pip install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch-0.2.0.post1-cp27-none-macosx_10_7_x86_64.whl 
pip install torchvision 
# OSX Binaries dont support CUDA, install from source if CUDA is needed
```

- Are you sure you select all correct options?
- Have you try the second command, `pip install torchvision`?

**Edit**

It seems in your log that you have `anaconda` installed on your mac, that mean you should have select **Package manager: `conda`** rather than **`pip`**.

In that case, you should remove the Package installed using pip:

```
pip uninstall torch
```

And use the command using anaconda instead:

- OS: OSX
- Package Manager: conda
- Python: 2.7
- CUDA: None

run the command:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c soumith
```

Comment: I have added the terminal response to doing this again in the question. Do you happen to know the terminal command to uninstall pytorch and I can try that?

Comment: @BrianPeach my pleasure, I'm sure you will not be the only one having this issue. Please take the time to check your install options next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using Docker is a good solution to have a reproducible environment and go around problems of setting up the environment. You can install docker from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/).  You can use the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/Dockerfile).

In case, if you need to install pytorch without the usage of docker even then, Dockerfile provides a good step by step approach to installing on local in a case when the operating system is the same as in its base Docker image.

You can also try using [datmo](https://datmo.com) in order setup environment and track machine learning projects for making models reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as you did, that might because of the version of numpy and I have solved this problem by upgrading my numpy package.

```
pip install -U numpy
```

And then things seem to go well~~